# Amazon Web Services Developer User Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an `Amazon Web Services` account which will be used to host the backed of an app.  The backend uses `PHP/MySQL` and will most likely use an `EC2` instance and `RDS`.  I have my own account which has access to everything.  I need to create an account for a developer to put the backend on AWS but I don't want them to have access to anything except what they need.  I know how to create `IAM` users and Groups but I don't know which permissions to grant the developer.  Under `Select Policy Template` there is a `Power User` template, is that good for a developer?  Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Power User Access** template in AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) grants permission to do ANYTHING except using IAM. A user with this permission can view, create or remove any resources in your AWS account, but they could not create new users or modify any user permissions.

It is recommended that you only give people the **least amount of privilege** required to use AWS, so that they do not intentional nor accidentally do something unwanted. However, if you do not have enough knowledge of AWS to know what functionality is required, you will most likely need to trust the developer to configure the system for your needs.

A few tips:

- Only give them access via an **IAM User** -- never give them your root credentials
- If you don't know what permissions are required, then "Power User" is at least safer than "Administrator" since they cannot edit IAM settings
- When they have completed their work, **revoke** their access so they cannot create any more AWS resources
- Determine whether you also wish to revoke access to the EC2 instances (you'll have to do this on the instances themselves)
- You may need to define some `roles` that will be used with Amazon EC2 -- these are defined in IAM, so the developer will not have permission to create the roles himself
- Ask the developer for documentation of what he has deployed
- Turn on [Detailed Billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/detailed-billing-reports.html) to identify what AWS charges you are receiving and check them against the documentation
- Turn on [CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create_trail_using_the_console.html) to activate auditing of your account (it is activated per-region)

Alternatively, you could do all the AWS configuration (launching an EC2 instance, creating the database) and only let the developer login to the EC2 instance itself. That way, they would not need access to your AWS account.

Comment: If I do what you suggested and do the configuration myself and let the developer login to the EC2 Instance itself, would I need to setup an IAM user for just that?  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Logging into an Amazon EC2 instance does not involve IAM permissions. Instead, it uses EC2 keypairs... For Windows, a random Administrator password is generated, which can be decoded using the keypair. For Linux, the keypair is used to ssh into EC2. These are for initial login only -- after that, you can add users and setup logins however you desire. So, you could give your Developer access to an instance, but not access to AWS.

Comment: I've created the ES2 instance and RDS instance.  Now I want to give a developer access using SSH.  I'm confused about the keypairs and pem file.  Do I send the developer the keys that were generated for SSH access or do I create a new user to get new keypairs.  I'm not Linux person.  The developer only needs enough privileges to deploy a PHP application to the EC2 and use MySQL on the RDS.  Your answers have helped a lot that I've gotten to this point.  I just need to allow the developer to use SSH.  Does he get public and private key for pem file?

Comment: I was thinking about using this for a guide, is this what I should be doing? http://brianflove.com/2013/06/18/add-new-sudo-user-to-ec2-ubuntu/

Comment: The EC2 keypairs are used to initially grant access to an EC2 instance. They should not be used as a regular means of access control. On Windows, change the Administrator password and create additional users (or attach to an AD domain). For Linux, have users create their own SSH keypairs, create a user on the Linux instance, then copy the public half of their keypair to the authorized_keys file. If you want more detail, post another question and people will gladly answer. See also: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html